# Looping through a nested JSON object based on Drop Downs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to iterate over a nested JSON object and return the values in different select boxes.

This is my JSON:

```
"games": [{
    "gameType": "RPG",
    "publishers": [{
        "publisher": "Square",
        "titles": [{
            "title": "Final Fantasy",
            "gameReleases": [ 2006, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2014 ]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

So when RPG is selected, the publishers drop down shows Square etc.

Currently i'm doing:

```
$('select#gameTypeCombo').on('change', function() {
    var getPublisher = _.pluck(info.games[0].gameType[0], 'publisher');
    var preparePublisher = _.map(getPublisher, function(val){ return '<option>' + val + '</option>';}).join();  
    $('select#publisher').html (preparePublisher).selectpicker('render');                          
})
```

Which populates the publisher box - but as im using `[0]` only the first one is selected, and it's no way of populating the subsequent drop downs.

I've been looking at $.each but can't get it to work.

Any advice appreciated

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Comment: I've tried following the fiddle but keep getting an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Array]' of undefined`

I'm using the same code (other than my first drop down doesn't have option values - as it's populated dynamically). Not sure how to get over this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/ThzqL/) that populates the second select based on the first select's value:

```
var info = {
    "games": [{
        "gameType": "RPG",
        "publishers": [{
            "publisher": "Square"
        }]
    },{
        "gameType": "Other",
        "publishers": [{
            "publisher": "Someone"
        }]
    }]
};

$('select#gameTypeCombo').on('change', function(e) {
    var $elem = $(this);
    var index = $elem.val();
    var getPublisher = _.pluck(info.games[index].publishers, 'publisher');
    var preparePublisher = _.map(getPublisher, function(val){ return '<option>' + val + '</option>';}).join();  
    $('select#publisher').html (preparePublisher);                          
});
```